# How can I link multiple c-files together using headers?

Tags: c, header, linker, c-preprocessor, program-entry-point

I work on a project that has multiple c files. Each c file has its own header. Now I want to put all c files together. 
As a preperation I have tried the following thing:

This would be my example c-code (function.c):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "function.h"

void output()
{
    printf("Thats a text\n");
}
```

Thats the associated header file (function.h):

```
//header function.h

#ifndef FUNCTION_H_
#define FUNCTION_H_

#endif // FUNCTION_H_
```

And thats my main.c:

```
#include "function.h"

int main()
{
    output();

    return 0;
}
```

I would expect the following output:

"Thats a text"

But I only receive following error:

undefined reference to 'output'

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why is your header empty? How do you compile and link?

Comment: Put `void output();` into your header file after the `#define`. This creates the declaration for the function that the _other_ file (e.g. `main.c`) needs

Comment: And compile your files together `cc function.c main.c -o main`.

Answer (score 2):

You need the [prototype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype) for `output` function in your header so that it's visible in other module(s).

```
//header function.h

#ifndef FUNCTION_H_
#define FUNCTION_H_

void output(void);

#endif // FUNCTION_H_
```

And you need to [*link*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) the module (source file `function.c`) in order to actually provide the definition of `output` that your main module uses.

For example, you can directly compile them together with:

```
gcc main.c function.c -o my_out
```

You may also want to look at [Makefiles](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your header should be

```
//header function.h

#ifndef FUNCTION_H_
#define FUNCTION_H_
void output();

#endif // FUNCTION_H_
```

compile like this:
(actual flags may depend on compiler used)

```
cc -c main.c
```

(creates main.o)

```
cc -c function.c
```

(creates function.o)

```
cc main.o function.o
```

(creates a.out or whatever your system default is)

...or as someone else mentioned:

```
cc main.c function.c
```

(does it all)